# Why does Oracle's varchar sort order not match the behavior of varchar comparison?

Tags: oracle, sorting, compare

An SQL statement like:

```
select * from (
  select '000000000000' as x from dual
  union
  select '978123456789' as x from dual
  union 
  select 'B002AACD0A' as x from dual
) /*where x>'000000000000'*/ order by x;
```

Yields:

```
B002AACD0A
000000000000
978123456789
```

After uncommenting the WHERE-restriction, the result is:

```
B002AACD0A
978123456789
```

I would have expected the result to be just `978123456789` since `B002AACD0A` is returned before `000000000000` when running the query without restriction.

How can this behavior be explained? And how am I supposed to sort and compare varchars so that they can work together like I can do with integers?

Funny enough, when changing the restriction to `x>'B002AACD0A'`, the result is empty. Changing it to`x>978123456789` returns `B002AACD0A`.

I.e. when comparing:

```
B002AACD0A > 978123456789 > 000000000000
```

But when sorting:

```
978123456789 > 000000000000 > B002AACD0A
```

When using binary sort explicitely (`order by NLSSORT(x,'NLS_SORT=BINARY_AI')`), the result is `B002AACD0A>978123456789>000000000000` and matches the behavior of comparison. But I still do not know why this is happening.

Comment: What version of oracle are you on?  I see something very different ... I get 000000000000, 978123456789, B002AACD0A with the first query, then 978123456789, B002AACD0A when the where uncommented.  My ver is 10.2.0.3.0.

Comment: I am using 10.2.0.4.0. I am not surprised to see the sort behaving different, probably related to the `NLS_SORT` setting (in my case, it is `GERMAN`). But anyway, I would expect sort and compare to behave in a similar way within a single query...

Comment: 9.2.0.7.0, 10.2.0.1.0, 11.2.0.1.0 and 11.1.0.6.0 (don't ask) all return 000000000000, 978123456789, B002AACD0A...

Comment: Thanks for checking this out. Seems to be a strange behavior on my DB only. :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Peter,

the behaviour of the sorting is regulated by the [`NLS_SORT`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams130.htm#i1130190) session parameter, whereas the behaviour for comparisons is dependent upon the [`NLS_COMP`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams120.htm#CHDGIIIG) parameter. You must have a mismatch.

I obtain the same result as you do with the following parameters:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2    FROM nls_session_parameters
  3   WHERE parameter IN ('NLS_COMP', 'NLS_SORT');

PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
NLS_SORT                       FRENCH
NLS_COMP                       BINARY
```

However when the two are matched the result is consistent:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_comp=LINGUISTIC;

Session altered

SQL> select * from (
  2    select '000000000000' as x from dual
  3    union
  4    select '978123456789' as x from dual
  5    union
  6    select 'B002AACD0A' as x from dual
  7  ) /*where x>'000000000000'*/ order by x;

X
------------
B002AACD0A
000000000000
978123456789

SQL> select * from (
  2    select '000000000000' as x from dual
  3    union
  4    select '978123456789' as x from dual
  5    union
  6    select 'B002AACD0A' as x from dual
  7  ) where x > '000000000000' order by x;

X
------------
978123456789
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for pointing this out, I did not know that there is a parameter called NLS_COMP.