# Aggregate function in result in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

Can any body tell me what will be result of aggregat function max for same value?
Suppose i have a creation_date column which contain date as varchar2 .If i try max(creation_date) what will be result and how will it select row.Is if use this in where clause subquery ,row is predictable or not?

full query is this.

create id from my_table where create_date=(select max(create_date) from my table);

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you want to get the latest date, then `MAX(create_date)` will not give you what you want. You will need to convert the `varchar2` to `date` first.

Comment: Ok..you give me hint.I just want to know how oracle aggregate function select any row if every value are same

Comment: It will return one of those values (It will always return a single value), however there is no way to predict which one of them it will return. Example: `SELECT MAX(col) FROM tbl` where `tbl.col` has the values (1, 2, 1, 4), it will return 1. Now is it the 1 from the first row or third row? No way to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very sure what are you trying to achieve.
Let us say there is a table my_table with data like what is given below. (Notice last two rows have same data in date columns)

SQL> select * from my_table;

```
 CREATE_ID CREATE_DATE         CREATE_DATE_VARCHAR
---------- ------------------- --------------------
         1 1996-07-25 00:00:00 1996-07-25 00:00:00
         2 1997-07-26 00:00:00 1997-07-26 00:00:00
         3 2013-07-26 00:00:00 2013-07-26 00:00:00
         4 2013-07-26 00:00:00 2013-07-26 00:00:00
```

If you execute `select * from my_table where create_date_varchar=(Select max(create_date_varchar) from my_table);`, then you would get 2 records (id 3 and 4)

```
 CREATE_ID CREATE_DATE         CREATE_DATE_VARCHAR
---------- ------------------- --------------------
         3 2013-07-26 00:00:00 2013-07-26 00:00:00
         4 2013-07-26 00:00:00 2013-07-26 00:00:00
```

If you want only one to be picked then you can use ROWNUM=1 `select * from my_table where create_date_varchar=(Select max(create_date_varchar) from my_table) and ROWNUM = 1;`
then you would get 1 record (either of 3 or 4, this can be controlled by using order clause)

Check: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d75a/3

Refer [Max Function](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefsqlj27781.html)
To read more about how sorting works refer [NLS_SORT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams130.htm#i1130190) and 
[Why does Oracle's varchar sort order not match the behavior of varchar comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190714/why-does-oracles-varchar-sort-order-not-match-the-behavior-of-varchar-compariso)

Comment: @user3004656 And that's the exact same as my answer to you in the comments. However, Kaushal made a nice extra effort to build a full example for you.