# Oracle sort order and greater than operator are not consistent on varchar column

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have a simple table

```
 CREATE TABLE TRIAL 
   (    "COL" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   )
```

and I insert there two values, '0', and 'A'.

The query

```
select * from trial order by col
```

returns

```
A
0
```

in this order, while the query

```
select * from trial where col>'A'
```

returns no results.
What could be the reason for such behaviour, and is there some simple trick, without changing db configuration, to get `order by` and `>` behave in a consistent manner?

**EDIT:**

to answer the comments:

```
select * from v$parameter where name like 'nls_sort'
```

returns

[image]

and

```
select dump(col,16),col from trial
```

returns

```
Typ=1 Len=1: 30 0
Typ=1 Len=1: 41 A
```

Comment: I tried the query and select * from trial order by col for me returns 0,A . Are you sure you are not missing something? Try select dump(col,16),col from  trial to see the ASCII code of each character.

Comment: Check your nls_sort parameter. `select * from v$parameter where name like 'nls_sort';`;

Comment: Not able to reproduce your first result set with provided sample values.  I can reproduce your second, as that is working correctly as the answer by Andrew demonstrated.

Comment: @StefanYordanov I just edited my question to answer yours

Comment: @FlorinGhita I edited the question to answer your comment as well

Comment: Are you running the two queries in the same client and session, without changing the NLS session parameters in between?

Comment: @AlexPoole I am running the queries from SQLDeveloper, so the answer to your question should be yes

Comment: OK, so what are NLS_SORT and NLS_COMP set to is you query NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS? I can duplicate what you see with binary/edbdic for example, but it would be interesting to see what you're actually using. (Read more about why these matter [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm))

Comment: @AlexPoole they are NLS_SORT: WEST_EUROPEAN, NLS_COMP: BINARY so this looks like the answer.

Comment: Yes, looks like this is really a duplicate of [the answer Andrew linked earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7191170/266304).

Comment: This is actually an issue with `NLS_SORT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be sorting by the binary/ASCII value of the string.

http://www.ascii-code.com/

Translating the values

- `0` => `48`
- `A` => `65`

When you sort by `col`, the default is ascending, so I would expect the `0` to come first, then the `A`.

When you ask for > 'A', you are asking for > 65, and neither 'A' or '0' is greater, so that makes sense.

As mentioned in the comments, I would check your sort `NLS_SORT` value to see if something is odd there for the sorting:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams130.htm#REFRN10127

You can also make sure this matches your `NLS_COMP` value:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams120.htm#REFRN10117

You can find more info in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7191170/137649

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE** : The actual issue turned out to be with `NLS_SORT` parameter. Please have a look at [Oracle – Case Insensitive Sorts & Compares/](http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/01/22/oracle-case-insensitive-sorts-compares) to get a good hold and understanding on the specific parameter value.

**Actual Issue**

The problem is actually due to `NLS_SORT` parameter value modified to `'WEST_EUROPEAN'` from `'BINARY'`.

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE TRIAL
  2     (    "COL" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
  3     );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO trial(col) VALUES('0');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO trial(col) VALUES('A');

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT * FROM trial ORDER BY col;

COL
--------------------
0
A
```

**NLS Parameter values**

```
SQL> SHOW PARAMETER NLS_SORT;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------
nls_sort                             string      BINARY

SQL> SHOW PARAMETER NLS_COMP;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------
nls_comp                             string      BINARY
```

Let's change the `NLS_SORT` parameter value:

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT='WEST_EUROPEAN';

Session altered.
```

**Error reproduce**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM trial ORDER BY col;

COL
--------------------
A
0
```

So, now the sorting of the values has changed with the change in the value of the `NLS_SORT` parameter.

Comment: I don't think you reproduced OP's result with `ORDER BY col`.

Comment: but then this does not explain the sort behaviour **as I see it**, does it?

Comment: @shawnt00 I don't think OP is stating complete details.

Comment: @LaitKumar I suspect that what I see is connected to the fact that the sort is "linguistic" instead of "binary" in my configuration. However your answer suggested to me a possible way out: select * from trial order by ascii(col). This is consistent with >. Thank you, I upvoted your answer for that.

Comment: @JohnDonn - there's also a function that allows you to explicitly override NLS_SORT: `... order by nlssort(col, 'nls_sort=binary')`. [Read more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch9sql.htm#NLSPG441). Might be clearer for whoever looks at your code in the future.

Comment: @AlexPoole I just figured it out. So many edits, so many comments, I just got confused. I have updated the answer, and removed my previous comments. Coffee didn't help today :-)

Comment: @JohnDonn I updated my answer based on your reply to Alex's question.

Comment: @JohnDonn LOL, I am still awake. I just hope the answer is clear to you now.